# Double data entry system using Infopath 2007 how to compare 2 infopath documents for differences?

Tags: infopath-2007

How to compare 2 infopath documents craeted using double data entry system for 
differences ?

We have a small project contains few infopath forms. Client is using double data entry system to reduce the errors. We are maintaining entry number in infopath form to seperate each entry.

> Note: I know we can compare xml data
>   files of 2 documents. (xml data file
>   has field names like field1,field2 and
>   so on..while on form that field1
>   represent some meaninngful text) But
>   the question is we want to compare it
>   Visually side by side. Any difference
>   should highlight the field.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use a different "comparison" form (instead of trying to alter the original). The new form can have two columns - two fields for each original field. You can load the two documents to compare into datasources (even make fields at the top which prompt for which two docs to compare). One shows in the left column and another in the right. Then just use conditional formatting to highlight where the first column doesn't match the second, or even hide the fields where they are identical so only the differences are visible.

If you want to get really fancy you can even let the user specify or change the values on the form and have them save back to the originals or create another new "merged" version.